# Why can't I query for by a user property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an app that stores entities with the owner's email. My models.py looks like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users

class GenericModel(db.Model):
    '''GenericModel is inherited by other model definitions.'''
    DateAdded = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    owner = db.UserProperty()

class CASentry(GenericModel):
    description = db.TextProperty()
    date = db.DateProperty()
    hours = db.FloatProperty()
    location = db.StringProperty()
```

When I run this from the interactive console on the development server:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
t = db.GqlQuery('''SELECT * FROM CASentry''').fetch(1)[0]
print t.owner

t = db.GqlQuery('''SELECT * FROM CASentry where owner = 'test@example.com' ''').fetch(1)
print t
```

I get this:

```
test@example.com
[]
```

I feel expect something like this:

```
test@example.com
[<models.CASentry object at 0x123456>]
```

Can anyone see a problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You should supply `User` instead of string:

```
t = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM CASentry where owner = :owner", owner=User(email="test@example.com")).fetch(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conversion to User directly in the GQL:

```
SELECT * FROM CASentry where owner = USER('test@example.com')
```